# Is there an automated program to find C++ linker errors?

Tags: c++, build-process, static-analysis, linker-errors

I'm working in a Linux environment with C++, using the GCC compiler.

I'm currently working on modifying and upgrading a large pre-existing body of code. As part of this, it has been necessary to add quite a large number of small references throughout the code in a variety of places to link things together, and also to add in several new external code libraries. There is also quite a large and complex structure of Makefiles linked to a configure.ac file to handle the build process.

Upon starting the build process everything compiles without a problem, but comes back with the dreaded linker error when trying to use a newly added custom code library we've created. We have now been through a vast amount of code with a fine tooth comb looking for spelling mismatches, checking the order that all the libraries are included in the build process, and checked that the .o files created contain what we need using dumps, and all are as and where they should be. We've also tested the library separately and the problem definitely doesn't lie there.

In short, we've tried most things that you should normally do in these scenarios.

Is there a tool for C++ that can detect linker errors automatically, in a similar vein to cppcheck or splint (both of which we have run to no avail) that could help here?

Comment: I think the *linker* does a pretty good job of detecting linker errors. What's the actual problem you are encountering?

Comment: +1 to Greg's comment... I can't think of a better or more automated tool than the linker to find link errors. It's exactly what an error thrown by the linker is in fact (crazy co-incidence? I think not!)

Comment: The linker has found the error, but there is no obvious cause to it. As I say, we have gone over everything to do with the problem area, and the areas above and below it in the code structure.

I guess what I'm after is some kind of deeper code analysis to try and find the exact cause of the linker error, rather than just stating there is one. Three people have spent several days trying to track this down now, so really this is a bit of a long shot / call out to the community to see if anyone knows anything that might help..

Comment: I agree - it's like asking for a tool to find compiler errors. Static analysis is there to help you find the errors that your compiler and linker do not tell you about.

Comment: Maybe you could post the actual linker error details. Then people could suggest a path to approach for solving it.

Comment: @greg An example of error in C that would be easy to find at compile-time, except it isn't by a classic linker for obvious reasons, is declaring `extern int t[];` in a file and `int *t;` in another. Does C++ have none of these pitfalls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know your platform, but I spent sometime with linker problems in gcc till I realized that the static library (`.a`) linking requires specific ordering, its not the same to link `gcc object.o first.a second.a` than `gcc object.o second.a first.a`.

Comment: We've been looking at this as a possible cause, and so far it doesn't seem to have made a difference. The main problem as I said is that its a large pre-existing code body, and the lead programmer on it is no longer with us. As a result, we're still working out exactly how the Configure file works.

We'll take a close look at the ordering though, cheers for the help!

Comment: After looking into it further, turns out there was one combination of ordering we hadn't tried, which magically (after the lovely 1-2 hour long build process) decided to work this time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW (not much) I try to tackle this sort of issue by using another linker as I have access to a couple of different platforms.  If you can use another linker you will find either:

a) the program links, which transforms your problem from 'why doesn't it link ?' to 'what are the differences between linkers and linking ?' which isn't exactly a step forward, but sometimes a step to one side gives you a different perspective from which you can see a solution;

OR

b) it fails to link, in which case the other linker might give more useful information about why it fails.

Comment: I like the idea of comparing two linker outputs, thats not an approach we've tried yet. Will give it a shot, cheers! Its mainly more detailed feedback on the error we're after - the current error isn't really that helpful at all..